# A specific term was first coined in a preprint but publication took many years. What to cite?

Tags: publications, citations, preprint

In my literature research for a paper I am writing I want to state that a specific term was first coined in a preprint from let's say 2000, but the paper was not published until 2005.

Unfortunately other papers I want to cite that were published in the years between used this term since it was known by then from the preprint. It would be strange if I mentioned both, the preprint from 2000 and the published version from 2005, but saying the term was first coined in the 2005 paper would not be correct.
Any ideas on how to handle that issue?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Why would it be strange to cite both? Surely anyone who delves into to reference list in sufficient detail would see the connection between the preprint and the publication.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what the term is (or what it’s relation is to the rest of your paper)?

Comment: I guess it's okay to cite both then...Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try this:

> Miller et al. (2000, p. 13) coined the term "underwater spaghetti knitting" (see also  Miller at al. 2005, p. 8).

Or this:

> This phenomenon became known as "underwater spaghetti knitting" (Miller et al. 2000, p. 13; Miller at al. 2005, p. 8).

Here, Miller et al. 2000 is the preprint and Miller et al. 2005 the final publication.